# Extract data from XML with ImportXML and XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to do is to extract data from this XML using Google Spreadsheets:

[XML File](https://api.eveonline.com/map/FacWarSystems.xml.aspx)

Now I thought that this would be an easy task and decided to use the ImportXML() function with following XPath sting:

```
- =IMPORTXML("https://api.eveonline.com/map/FacWarSystems.xml.aspx", "//row[@owningFactionID='500002']")
```

Which, in theory should return every entry in the document where the owningFactionID is 500002.

Problem is that I only get #N/A in the Google Spreadsheet (Empty).

If someone could help with what I'm doing wrong here I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is correct, but the row elements that are being returned are empty. I assume you want to see the attributes on each row. You need to use something like:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://api.eveonline.com/map/FacWarSystems.xml.aspx","//row[@owningFactionID='500002']/@*")
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Small follow up question: Is there a way to display this in an array like row[1]  to row[42] to be able to tell how many of the items fit the requirements or would that be easier to achieve using regex on that xml doc?

Comment: @BlubQ I am not too familiar with IMPORTXML. I think you would have more luck opening the script editor and writing a function with apps script that parses the XML into the format you want. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#parse_xml